# Passing props to a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello StackExchange community.

I'm new to react and having some difficulty calling a function exported from another file:

When i attempt to call this function from a form i receive the error:

```
Attempted import error: 'PrivateRoute' is not exported from '../components/PrivateRoute'.
```

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/", state: { referer: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

The file i am attempting to call it from:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { PrivateRoute } from "../components/PrivateRoute";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    width: 471,
    height: 467,
    padding: "38px 40px",
    fontFamily: "Avenir Next",
    fontSize: 32,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#000000",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  bottomBar: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: "0",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: "0 15px",
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    display: "flex",
    padding: "15px",
  },
  bottomRight: {
    marginLeft: "auto",
    padding: "15px",
  },
  p: {

  },
  space: {
    width: "30px",
  },
  smallText: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    fontWeight: "300",
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: "10px",
  },
  form: {
    marginTop: "10%",
    height: "70%",
    position: "relative",
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: "10px",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "0",
    bottom: "0",
  },
  password: {
    fontSize: "12px",
    textAlign: "right",
    fontWeight: "600",
  },
}));


const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div style={{height: "calc(100% - 60px)", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Box>Agents of Radical</Box>
        <Box className={classes.smallText}>Portal Sign In</Box>
          <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={PrivateRoute()}>
            <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" className={classes.input}/>
            <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password" className={classes.input}/>
            <p className={classes.password}>Forgot Password?</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"  className={classes.button}/>
        </form>
      </Paper>
      <Box className={classes.bottomBar}>
        <div className={classes.bottomLeft}>
          <p className={classes.p}>Privacy</p>
          <div className={classes.space}></div>
          <p className={classes.p}>Terms</p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.bottomRight}>
          <p className={classes.p}>Help</p>
        </div>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Did I export this function incorrectly? What is the correct way to pass props to this function to get it to fun?

I am attempting to call the function from using onSubmit in my form.

Any help / guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Use default import versus named import, i.e.  `import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute";`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a default export, so import like below

```
import PrivateRoute from "../components/PrivateRoute";
```

Answer (score 1):

Note; we have two ways of exporting functions or classes/constrcutional functions in javascript:

1. as default which is the one you did for privateRoute e.g:

export default functionOrClassName

2. as a module part(then you dont use the word default) e.g: export const functionOrClassName

---If you also want to export two or more fucntions as a defualt (may be a group of utils functions), you can then do this at the very bottom:
export default{
functionA,
functionB,
....
}

---If you also want to export two or more module part not as default,
then you can do this depending on where the modules are located, then can be in another file and be exported from another file called maybe "globalTypesExport":
export {functionA,functionB,...} from '../..'

**How to import the different exports types**

1. to import a default, you just do: import functionName from '...'
2. to import a module part, you just do: import {functionName} from '....

Welcome to react

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, i appreciate it!